# Connecting Caché database in Azure function

Tags: python, azure-functions, intersystems-cache, intersystems

I'm looking to a way to "simply" access to a Caché database using python (I need to make sql query on this database).
I've heard about a python package (Intersys) but I can't find it anymore (having this package would be the most simple way).
I've tried using pyodbc connection with the appropriate Caché driver : it works on my machine, however when I try to deploi the function in production (Linux OS), the driver's file is not found.
Thank you

Comment: does this helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/47722923

Comment: Thank you but no. Caché is a database type developped by Intersystem

Answer (score 0):

There is only one way, on how to make it work with Python, is using pydobc, and InterSystems driver.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Do you know if a Linux driver exists for Caché database ?

Comment: Yes, you can take it from the bin folder from the installed instance.